# Интеграция facebook формы приглашения друзей на сайте

Tags: javascript, facebook

При статическом вызове - отображается нужная форма, но при загрузке через jQuery.load() в консоль пишется `<fb:serverfbml> requires the "fbml" attribute.`

Документация от facebook изучена уже вдоль и поперек.

Как заставить работать этот скрипт при динамическом отображении на странице???

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : '12886800000000',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());

</script>

<fb:serverfbml>
    <script type="text/fbml">
        <fb:fbml>
            <fb:request-form
                method="POST"
                type="MY_APP"
                action="MY_SITE_LINK"
                content="
                    <fb:name
                        uid='FB_USER_ID'
                        useyou='false'
                        firstnameonly='true'
                        linked='false' />
                    wants you to try out the MY_APP.
                    <fb:req-choice url='MY_SITE_LINK' label='Join!' />
                ">
                <fb:multi-friend-selector
                    showborder="false"
                    email_invite="false"
                    actiontext="Invite your friends to use MYAPP."
                    import_external_friends="false"/>

            </fb:request-form>
        </fb:fbml>
    </script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут думаю проблема в том, что нельзя динамически загрузить тэг `<fb:serverfbml>`. Он должен заранее быть на странице. То есть:

```
<div id="fb-root"><fb:serverfbml id="fbTest"></fb:serverfbml></div>
```

Затем Вы можете динамически подгрузить контент вида

```
<script type="text/fbml"> ... </script>
```

в элемент fbTest.

Попробуйте

Comment: Ок, буду завтра на работе, попробую. Спасибо, за совет.

Comment: Не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

В результате решением стало [Fb:serverFbml on Canvas Iframe](http://af-design.com/blog/2010/11/23/fbserverfbml-on-canvas-iframe/).
Очень неоднозначно, но работает.

Если у кого-то есть желание поделится опытом о работе с facebook и его APIs, буду очень рад.

Answer (score 0):

тоже долго боролась с подгрузкой fb:request-form в всплывающем попапе. Посмотрите вот эту статью: 
http://fbexchange.net/questions/19/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-dynamically-load-serverfbml-content-into-my-iframe-app-pa

PS. У меня заработало, если все еще актуально - могу выложить кусочек кода.